# rails admin - scss error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, rails-admin

I installed rails admin and am getting an error when trying to access `/admin`:

[image]

My `Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.11'

gem 'devise'
gem 'rails_admin'

gem 'pg'
gem 'haml'

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'therubyracer'
  gem 'less-rails'
  gem 'coffee-script'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

I have custom less styles in `app/assets/stylesheets/*`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be twitter bootstrap & rails admin incompatibility.

Rails admin tried to load the `bootstrap.less` located in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

Solution: Rename `bootstrap.less` to `bootstrap-mine.less`.